# Get no of attempts in quartz

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Can any one please tell me how can I get current attempt count in quartz.

Example :  if Quartz scheduler is started with repeat count of 5. I want to get the current repeat count.

Here is the Example I am trying with

```
 public class SimpleTriggerExample  implements Job 
 {
  int count = 0;
 JobDetail job = null;
 JobDataMap data = null;

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
     new SimpleTriggerExample().schedule();

}
public void schedule() throws ParseException, SchedulerException{
     job = JobBuilder.newJob(SimpleTriggerExample.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInSeconds(10).withRepeatCount(3))

            .build();
        System.out.println("before in main jobdatamap");

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

            //count
     data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    System.out.println("after jobdatamap");

            int count1 = data.getInt("EXECUTION_COUNT");
            System.out.println("count1-->before"+count1);
            count1++;
            System.out.println("count1-->after"+count1);

            job.getJobDataMap().put("EXECUTION_COUNT", count1);

            count = count1;

            System.out.println("count"+count);


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JobDataMap along with @PersistJobDataAfterExecution annotation.

Make sure when you modify data in JobDataMap the key value should be same.

If you do like this you can persist your attempts as per your requirement.

Example Code Snippet:

```
package com.mss.quartz.demo;

 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;

 import org.quartz.InterruptableJob;
 import org.quartz.Job;
  import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
 import org.quartz.JobDataMap;
 import org.quartz.JobDetail;
 import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
 import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
 import org.quartz.JobKey;
 import org.quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecution;
 import org.quartz.Scheduler;
 import org.quartz.SchedulerContext;
 import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
 import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder;
 import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
 import org.quartz.UnableToInterruptJobException;
 import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
 @PersistJobDataAfterExecution
 public class HelloJob implements InterruptableJob
 {  
SchedulerContext schedulerContext  = null;
testQuartz test = new testQuartz();

boolean result;
private boolean _interrupted = false;
private JobKey _jobKey = null;
Thread t = null;
//public static int count = 0;

public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
    System.out.println("---" + this._jobKey + "  -- INTERRUPTING --");
    this._interrupted = true;
}
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
throws JobExecutionException {
    Scheduler scd = context.getScheduler();


    JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

    String jobSays = dataMap.getString("test1");

    int myFloatValue = dataMap.getIntValue("id");

    System.out.println("In Job Class"+jobSays+ "  "+myFloatValue+"   Current time in 

   Job class  "+new Date().toString());
    JobKey jobKey = context.getJobDetail().getKey();
    int attemps = dataMap.getInt("attempts");
    attemps++;
    dataMap.put("attempts", attemps);
    System.out.println("After putting count in job data map:"+dataMap.get("attempts"));




}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the @PersistJobDataAfterExecution annotation to SimpleTriggerExample class:

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
 public class SimpleTriggerExample  implements Job 
 { ...}
```